# reference to figures in the appendix is not correct in REVTEX

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, appendices

I would appreciate any help with a problem that I have with reference to figures in my appendix. For example, instead of (Fig. A.1 ), I only get (Fig. A). I read all the previous posts but they did not help me. According to a previous post, I even added

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
```

after the \appendix command, but that did not help either. Here is the minimal code I use:

```
\documentclass[reprint,
superscriptaddress,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-1}


\section{AAA}\label{AAA}
Blah blah Fig. \ref{xyz}  blah blah.

\appendix
\section{ BBB}\label{BBB}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{xyz.png}
\caption{blah blah}
\end{center}\label{xyz}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Change `\begin{center}` into `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`.

Comment: This produces the desired output: `\documentclass[reprint,
superscriptaddress,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{AAA}
\label{AAA}
Blah blah Fig. \ref{xyz}  blah blah.

\appendix
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

\section{BBB}\label{BBB}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{blah blah}
\label{xyz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}` Do you get something different?

Comment: The question is a duplicate; in the linked question the `centering` environment was used, but the problem is just the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Gonzalo Medina. The problem is now solved.